# Geometry shader producing gaps between lines

Tags: opengl, glsl

I wrote a geometry shader to compute the intersection contour of a mesh and a plane, but at the intersection points there are sometimes 1 pixel wide gaps between two lines.

[image]

The shader first computes the signed distances of the triangle vertices to the plane. It then checks if two distances have a different sign to determine if there is an intersection with an edge. If so, it emits a vertex at the intersection, which is computed as the weighted average between the edge points.

```
#version 330
layout(triangles) in;
layout(line_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

out vec3 vertexPosition;

uniform vec3 planePos;
uniform vec3 planeNormal;
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
uniform vec2 screenSize;

void intersection(in vec4 a, in float distA, in vec4 b, in float distB)
{
  if (sign(distA) * sign(distB) <= 0.0f && !(sign(distA) == 0 && sign(distB) == 0))
  {
    float fa = abs(distA);
    float fb = abs(distB);
    float fab = fa + fb;
    vec4 ptIntersection;
    // Don't divide by zero.
    if (fab < 0.001)
      ptIntersection = (a + b) * 0.5;
    else
      ptIntersection = (fa * b + fb * a) / fab;
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * ptIntersection;
    vertexPosition = gl_Position.xyw;
    EmitVertex();
  }
}

void main()
{
  vec4 a = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
  vec4 b = gl_in[1].gl_Position;
  vec4 c = gl_in[2].gl_Position;

  float distA = dot(a.xyz - planePos, planeNormal);
  float distB = dot(b.xyz - planePos, planeNormal);
  float distC = dot(c.xyz - planePos, planeNormal);

  intersection(a, distA, b, distB);
  intersection(b, distB, c, distC);
  intersection(c, distC, a, distA);
}
```

I know it's kind of cheap, as I've ignored the special case where all three points lie on the plane. The `!(sign(distA) == 0 && sign(distB) == 0)` makes sure that if two points lie on the plane, no vertex will be emitted for that edge. So if all three lie on the plane, there will be no output. But I guess that's not necessarily a bad thing. What I like about it is that there is no crazy branching, and I'd like to keep it that way if possible.

So I'm wondering: Why do I see these gaps? Let's say there are two triangles (a,b,c) and (c,b,d). a and b are above the plane, c and d below. For the first triangle, the shader generates the intersection with (b,c), for the second the intersection with (c,b). Assuming that the addition of two floats is commutative, then the `intersection` function is symmetrical wrt the inputs, so the results should be the same. Why do I still see these gaps?

Comment: Did you ask this question before?

Comment: @Nicol Yes, but after a couple minutes I realized that my initial analysis was wrong, so I deleted it.

Comment: Did you try using invariant qualifiers?

Comment: Are you sure it is not a z-buffer problem? I just ask because of the little _corner_ in the middle of the green line. I there would expect,  if it is a calculation problem in the geometry shader, either a horizontal or vertical gab there and not such a _corner_.

Comment: The little corner just occurs where the line rasterizer switches from horizontal to vertical.

Comment: Exactly. And yes I'm sure @t.niese, depth testing is disabled.

Comment: @Daniel, no I didn't use `invariant`. On which variables would I use that?

Comment: Upon looking at the spec again (section 4.6.1), variance explicitly refers to computations in different programs. So it shouldn't have anything to do with the case at hand... But for completeness: You would (re-)declare all shader in-/output variables at global scope (e.g. invariant gl_Position;)

Comment: In this shader there is probably an error. If the vertex shader sends `gl_Position=gl_Vertex` to the geometry shader, then the emitted vertex of the geometry shader must be `gl_Position = projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix * ptIntersection;` in the case the `uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix` is in fact an affine matrix and not the `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix`

Comment: You're right, the naming is bad. It's the MVP matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in the specification of the Bresenham line rasterization algorithm that the OpenGL specification gives. Quote from the OpenGL 3.3 [Spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec33.core.20100311.withchanges.pdf), section 3.5.1:

> Rasterizing the line segment starting at pa and ending at pb produces those fragments f for which the segment starting at pa and ending on pb intersects Rf, except if pb is contained in Rf [diamond region centered on the fragment].

With the effect that the endpoint is not rasterized at all if two neighboring lines of yours unfortunately run in opposite directions (i.e. end in the same point) and that endpoint is contained in said diamond around the pixel center. Thus you will see a noticeable gap.

As you are already using geometry shaders, you can of course (with a bit of additional calculation) emit triangles to make a "true" wide line.

Comment: a simpler solution would be to make the lines run in consistent directions, e.g. positively along planeNormal cross triangleNormal

Comment: Very nice. I verified it by the definitely more stupid but even simpler solution: `intersection(a, distA, b, distB); intersection(b, distB, c, distC); intersection(c, distC, a, distA); intersection(a, distA, b, distB);`

Answer (score 2):

Here's the final code, might be useful to someone.

```
#version 330

layout(triangles) in;
layout(line_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

uniform vec4 plane;
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;

void emitIntersection(in vec4 a, in float distA, in vec4 b, in float distB)
{
  if (sign(distA) * sign(distB) <= 0.0f && !(sign(distA) == 0 && sign(distB) == 0))
  {
    float fa = abs(distA);
    float fb = abs(distB);
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * ((fa * b + fb * a) / (fa + fb));
    EmitVertex();
  }
}

void main()
{
  float dist[3];
  for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    dist[i] = dot(gl_in[i].gl_Position, plane);

  // Find the smallest i where vertex i is below and vertex i+1 is above the plane.
  ivec3 ijk = ivec3(0, 1, 2); // use swizzle to permute the indices
  for (int i=0; i < 3 && (dist[ijk.x] > 0 || dist[ijk.y] < 0); ijk=ijk.yzx, i++);

  emitIntersection(gl_in[ijk.x].gl_Position, dist[ijk.x], gl_in[ijk.y].gl_Position, dist[ijk.y]);
  emitIntersection(gl_in[ijk.y].gl_Position, dist[ijk.y], gl_in[ijk.z].gl_Position, dist[ijk.z]);
  emitIntersection(gl_in[ijk.z].gl_Position, dist[ijk.z], gl_in[ijk.x].gl_Position, dist[ijk.x]);
}
```