# Intersection of a mesh with a parametric surface

Tags: opengl, language-agnostic, geometry, collision-detection, intersection

I'm wondering how a precise algorithm can be written to compute the frontier of the surface of intersection between a parametric surface `f : R^2 --> R^3`  and a triangulated mesh.

I've thought to a first approach:

```
nStepsU = 100
nStepsV = 100
tolerance=0.01 // pick some sensical value
intersectionVertices={}
for  u from minU to maxU in nStepsU:
    for v from minV to maxV in nStepsV:
        for v in verticesInMesh:
             if euclidean distance( f(u,v), v ) < tolerance:
                 add vertex v in a set

connect the vertices in intersectionVertices with a line strip
draw the vertices in intersectionVertices
```

This algorithm, is very simple but slow (n^3) and does not keep in account that the topography of the mesh is based on triangles so the output points are points of the mesh and not points computed exploiting the intersection of surface with the triangles and is heavily dependent of the tolerance one has to set.

Has someone some better idea or can one drive me to a suitable library for this purpose?

Comment: Do you have any additional information about the surface? Can you project efficiently? Can you find efficiently on which side of it a point is?

Comment: The surface is an helicoid `x(r,theta) = r*cos(theta)`,`y(r,theta) = theta`,`z(r,theta) = r*sin(theta)` so is impossible to distinguish an inside and an outside

Comment: Oh, right. So my answer isn't exactly spot on. But you can still determine theta and r from (x,y,z), and compute a signed distance from that. What I'm not clear about though is, how precise do you expect this to be? What if one triangle intersects with the surface multiple times in the y-direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would iterate over each triangle, and compute the intersection of the triangle with the surface. I would use a geometry shader which takes the triangles as input, and outputs line strips. For each vertex in the triangle, compute the signed distance to the surface. Then iterate over the edges: If there are two vertices where `h` has different signs, the edge between these vertices intersects with the surface. While I'm sure the exact intersection can be computed, the easiest solution would be to interpolate linearly, i.e.

```
vec3 intersection = (h0 * v1 + h1 * v0) / (h0 + h1);
```

Then output each intersection as a vertex of your line segment.

The code I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884423/geometry-shader-producing-gaps-between-lines/16886843) can get you started. If you want to just draw the result, you will probably run into the same problem that I described in that question. If you need the vertices on the client, you can use [transform feedback](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback).

Edit: I just did a little test. As the distance function I used

```
float distToHelicoid(in vec3 p)
{
  float theta = p.y / 5 + offset.x / 50;
  float a = mod(theta - atan(p.z, p.x), 2*PI) - PI; // [-PI, PI[
  if (abs(a) > PI/2)
    a = mod(theta - atan(-p.z, -p.x), 2*PI) - PI;
  return a;
}
```

Since there is no inside/outside, and this distance function goes from -90° to 90°, you can only emit vertices if the sign goes from small negative to small positive or vice versa, not when it flips from 90° to -90°. Here I simply filtered out distances where abs(dist) > 45°:

[image]

The clean way would be to determine the index of the closest revolution. E.g. [-pi, pi] would be revolution 0, [pi, 3pi] = revolution 1, etc. You would then only emit if two distances refer to the same revolution.

Comment: I like your approach, the only thing here is that I need to better study geometry shaders as I've always found them very complicate to understand. I've also thought, in order to reduce the complexity to use a custom vertex shader that colors the vertex where the proximity condition is respected as red. Do you have any good link that documents how to upload triangles to geometry shaders?

Comment: A geometry shader gets its input from the vertex shader, so you don't have to do anything different than what you would normally do. Instead of your normal vertex+fragment shader program you just also attach a geometry shader. Then use the program as always and draw your geometry. So it's actually very easy to integrate. See [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader) for how it fits in the pipeline.

Comment: @linello I added a distance function for the helicoid.

Comment: Your suggestion is very useful for me. I've managed to get the plane intersection geometry shader working but I've problems with the modelview matrix and the world coordinates of the emitted vertices. My vertex shader is a plain simple `gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*gl_Vertex` and I always get the vertices strip with the wrong z, how should I write the vertex shader?

Comment: Oh. right. I don't do any transformation in the vertex shader, it simply forwards the vertex positions, `gl_Position = gl_Vertex`. The geometry shader then applies the MVP matrix when it emits the vertices. So you **do** have to do something a little different.

Comment: Oh thanks for this suggestion! Now I have a passthrough vertex shader like the one you suggested. I would also correct you in the other question, in the line where you are outputting the ptIntersection vertex you need a projection matrix too! I thought it was just the modelview matrix `ptIntersection = (fa * b + fb * a) / fab;         gl_Position = projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix*ptIntersection;`

Comment: I'm having hard times figuring out how to translate a parametric helicoid equation to the shader language.
How should I write my helicoid intersection function if my helicoid is like
`x(r,theta)=r cos(theta)` `y(r,theta)`= c*theta` `z(r,theta)=r sin(theta)` ?

I don't understand why you call theta the vertex `y` and how is possible to shift the helicoid...

Comment: You have an equation `(x,y,z) = f(theta, r)`. What I'm doing is solve for `theta` and `r`. Solving for theta is easiest, because y only depends linearly on theta, and is independent of r: `y=c*theta`, so `theta=y/c`. Geometrically speaking, I'm intersecting the helicoid with the plane through (0,y,0) with normal (0,1,0). To shift the helicoid, you offset y. Alternatively you can offset theta, because of their linear relationship. In other words, translating the helicoid upwards is the same as rotating it on the y axis.

Comment: I've modified the shader to include the offset as you suggested:
`float distToHelicoid(in vec3 p, in vec3 offset,float baseTheta)
{
    float helicoidC = 1.0;
    float theta = (p.y -offset.y)/helicoidC+baseTheta;
    float a = mod(theta - atan(p.z-offset.z, p.x-offset.x), 2*PI) - PI; // [-PI, PI[
    return a;
}
`
where the helicoidC is your `c` parameter. I would also like to compute a better intersection point instead of using interpolation because in some situations I get very zigzaggy lines.

Answer (score 1):

If your surface is always helicoid, you can try to project everything on a cylinder around axis Y.

The surface of helicoid consists of lines orthogonal to the surface of that cylinder and after projection you will get a spiral. After projection of 3D triangle mesh onto that cylinder you will get 2D triangle mesh (note that some areas may be covered with several layers of triangles).

So the task becomes finding triangles in 2D triangle mesh intersecting the spiral which is simpler. If you are OK with approximations, you can segment that spiral and use some kind of tree to find triangles intersecting the spiral.

When you have a triangle intersecting part of spiral, its intersection will be a segment, you can just recalculate 3D coordinates of the segment and set of these segments is your intersection line.